# cplex optimization studio searching path

Tags: path, cplex, ilog

When trying to run on my computer an opl model (file .mod and .dat) that work on another computer I get the error "can't find file". More precisely the .dat file connect to an excel sheet that cplex seems not able to see it. I don't know how to specify the search path ? ( the excel file is in the same file as the others).

If I give an absolute path I get "invalid escape sequence in \R", and have no idea what it means.

Any help welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

If the Excel file is in the same same directory as the .dat file:

```
 SheetConnection sheet("FileName.xlsb");
```

If you want to use absolute path, use the escape character \, example:

```
 SheetConnection sheet("C:\\dir1\\FileName.xlsb");
```

You should also check for the other PATH variables after copying over a new host, or migrating. In Cplex Optimisation Studio, open the projcet, then:
OPL Project View -> Right click (on your project) -> Resource -> Lined Resources

Check all paths, in particular PROJECT_LOC